# Python console within Pycharm in a Ubuntu Virtualbox fails to connect

Tags: ubuntu, docker, virtualbox, pycharm, divio

I'm using [Aldryns](https://www.divio.com/en/products/aldryn-cloud/) environment to develop a django-cms site.

I'm on windows 10, which isn't perfect, so I created a virtual machine Ubuntu 16.04 with Virtualbox. Within the VM, I installed Pycharm 2016.1.3.

Aldryn support (who are tireless) helped me to [setup docker](http://support.divio.com/hc/en-us/articles/208181815) support for Ubuntu and Pycharm:

> just create a file `/etc/default/docker` containing:
>
> ```
> DOCKER_OPTS="-H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2376"
> ```
>
> Drop the following into `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/daemon.conf`
>
> (create directories if they don't exist yet):
>
> ```
> [Service]    
>     EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/docker    
>     ExecStart=   
>     ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon $DOCKER_OPTS
> ```
>
> Then issue the following two commands:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl daemon-reload 
> sudo systemctl restart docker
> ```

Now Pycharm is able to see within the docker container. 
I.e. the Project Interpreter nicely shows all installed packages.

I did do all this, so I would be able to use the python console from Pycharm.

(ERROR: Interactive mode is not yet supported on Windows.)

Now I get this error:

> xyz_w:python /opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py 0 0
>
> PyDev console: starting.
>
> Couldn't connect to console process.
>
> Process finished with exit code 143

Playing it via a terminal gives:

```
me@my-VirtualBox:~/xyz$ docker-compose run --rm web python manage.py shell
```

> /app/addons/aldryn-django/aldryn_config.py:56:
>
> RuntimeWarning:
>
> no cache configured. Falling back to CACHE_URL=locmem://
>   RuntimeWarning,
>
> Django not found.
>
> Python 2.7.11 (default, Mar  3 2016,
>   10:57:12)  [GCC 4.9.2] on linux2 Type "help", "copyright", "credits"
>   or "license" for more information. (InteractiveConsole)

How do I solve this problem, so I will be able to use the python console?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall docker integration plugin to get PyCharm's bundled version. (Make sure you have a new Pycharm version.)

Source:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-18853#comment=27-1362538